# How to add animate images and text in the same view programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimage, uitextview

I am currently learning iOS development and I want to develop an iOS app where there is an animated image at the beginning top of the View Controller and a lot of text just after it. Please have a look at the picture below:

[image: How I want the image and text to appear on the view]

I have thought about the codes for both the image animation at the top and the large amount of text just after it. I was wondering whether someone could please review them and tell me whether they are fine or not.

The codes for both the image animation and the large amount of text will be placed inside the viewDidLoad method of the implementation file of the controller like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // codes for image animation 

    // codes for large amount of text to be displayed

}
```

**IMAGE ANIMATION CODES**

For the image animation, I am going to use 5 png pictures: A.png, B.png, C.png, D.png and E.png. The slide show will start from A, then move on to B, then to C, to D and finally to E. All the 5 pictures are added to my project in Xcode. Below are the codes:

```
NSArray *imagelist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"A.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"B.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"C.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"D.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"E.png"],nil];

UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(5,5,90,180)];
animationImageView.animationImages = imagelist;
animationimageView.animationDuration = 10;
[self.view addSubView:animationimageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];
```

**LARGE AMOUNT OF TEXT CODES**

For the text, I have not added all the necessary text....because there is a lot more. That is why I need the text object to be scrollable. Below are the codes:

```
UITextView *largeText = [[UITextView alloc] initWitthFrame: CGRectMake(5,100,90,180)];
largeText.text = @"In organizations, we must work with and for others. To be able to mutually achieve our goals, we must be able to relate to others effectively. These leadership tips will help you do just that:
1)Catch people doing things right and then let them know that they are doing things right
2)Use feedback to stay informed about what other people are doing in your area of responsibility and authority
3)Have regular, focused meetings regarding the projects that you are responsible for
4)Provide adequate instructions. Time is lost if things are not done correctly
5)Train others to do jobs. You cannot do them all, nor can others do them if they have not been trained
6)Expect others to succeed. It becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy when you believe others are loyal, dedicated and doing a good job";
largeText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" size:18];
largeText.editable = NO;
largeText.scrollEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubView:largeText];
```

Please review the codes and can someone tell me whether the codes are fine or not.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *imagelist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"A.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"B.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"C.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"D.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"E.png"],nil];

UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(5,5,90,180)];
[self.view addSubView:animationimageView];

 NSTimeInterval delay=0.0;
 for (NSInteger i=0; i<[imagelist count]; i++) {
         delay+=3.0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            animationImageView.image=[imagelist objectAtIndex:i];
        }completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain the code? Thanxs

Comment: Please explain why my own codes in my post will not work?